# How to Get Individual Custom Post-Type Item using WordPress REST API

Tags: jquery, ajax, custom-post-type, wordpress-rest-api

I have a custom post-type called `product` which has a single post with a title, no post content, and a bunch of custom meta. My jQuery code below is returning a 404 error. As yet, I haven't found anything in the WP Rest API docs about getting individual custom post-types posts, though I do see that you can do so with the `post` post-type. Is what I'm trying to do even possible yet?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $( '#product-select' ).on( 'change', function(){ //changing a drop-down triggers the function
        var productID = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/wp-json/wp/v2/types/product/137', // <= /product works but /product/137 does not
            success: function( data ){
                console.log( data );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Well 404 means your ressource was not found. Usually what this url in your rest api means is you are trying to get a product with the id of 137. I guess that this one is not to be found. if you leave the 137 and and just use /product, what does it return?

Answer (score 1):

The URL is `/wp-json/wp/v2/product` - remove the "type" path. 
And check you have `show_in_rest` set to true while registering your cpt.

Thats also a pretty common use case so a google search for "wordpress rest api custom post type" would've shown you this easily.

See documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/